# Data manipulation questions

Tags: r

I want to create two new columns called `prey`, and `preyrow`. `prey` is the next position `y` value, but within same `x` value. And `preyrow` value is the next position `row` value within same `x` value.

Raw table as follows:

```
   x           y row
1  1  0.60697546   1
2  1 -0.68600911   2
3  1 -0.53499454   3
4  1  0.05591587   4
5  2  0.11937963   5
6  2 -0.39951846   6
7  2  0.97430697   7
8  3  0.42852135   8
9  3  0.27695563   9
10 4 -0.29530769  10
```

I want the output table to look like:

```
   x           y row        prey prerow
1  1  0.60697546   1 -0.68600911      2
2  1 -0.68600911   2 -0.53499454      3
3  1 -0.53499454   3  0.05591587      4
4  1  0.05591587   4          NA     NA
5  2  0.11937963   5 -0.39951846      6
6  2 -0.39951846   6  0.97430697      7
7  2  0.97430697   7          NA     NA
8  3  0.42852135   8  0.27695563      9
9  3  0.27695563   9 -0.29530769     10
10 4 -0.29530769  10          NA     NA
```

Comment: What's the logic to calculate the prey and prerow columns, why some are NA?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you require (using `data.table`):

```
require(data.table)
df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), 
      y = c(0.60697546, -0.68600911, -0.53499454, 0.05591587, 0.11937963, 
      -0.39951846, 0.97430697, 0.42852135, 0.27695563, -0.29530769), 
      row = 1:10), .Names = c("x", "y", "row"), class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
dt <- data.table(df, key="x")
dt.out <- dt[, .SD[2:(nrow(.SD)+1)], by=x]
setnames(dt.out, c("x", "prey", "preyrow"))
dt.out <- cbind(dt, subset(dt.out, select=-c(x)))

> dt.out

    x           y row        prey preyrow
 1: 1  0.60697546   1 -0.68600911       2
 2: 1 -0.68600911   2 -0.53499454       3
 3: 1 -0.53499454   3  0.05591587       4
 4: 1  0.05591587   4          NA      NA
 5: 2  0.11937963   5 -0.39951846       6
 6: 2 -0.39951846   6  0.97430697       7
 7: 2  0.97430697   7          NA      NA
 8: 3  0.42852135   8  0.27695563       9
 9: 3  0.27695563   9          NA      NA
10: 4 -0.29530769  10          NA      NA
```